# Method Not Found Execption

Tags: ejb

So, I am developing an app which helps the employes of a company to manage the daily operations.
Being this my first project in which i use the EJB logic, I have encountered some problems....PLEASE HELP ME :)

/the log/

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #(tipoFornitoreBean.remove): javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.bmw.vss.web.bean.TipoFornitoreBean"10ee602.remove()
```

/the bean/

```
private void remove()
{
        TipoFornitoreDetails 
           details=null;
        short id=details.getId();
        TFF.delete(id);
      }
```

/the html/

```
<h:commandButton image="../images/Elimina.gif" value="#{Tfr.id}" onclick="if (!confirm('Vuoi rimuovere il Tipo Fornitore')) return false" action="#{tipoFornitoreBean.remove}">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{tipoFornitoreBean.tipoFornitoreDetails.id}" value="#{Tfr.id}" />
```

ps. maybe there are some problems in the code of the method, but i cant understand why the program doesnot know any of the bean methods.

Answer (score 0):

Change scope of remove method to public

```
public void remove(){

}
```